# Is there a way to configure a default 5xx error message in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-status-codes

I’m new to Ruby/Rails and working on my team’s web app. I am wondering if there is a way to configure the app so that any 5xx http status error will give the client the same generic error message (in an effort to maintain security).

Ideally the configuration will overwrite any new 5xx errors too that may be given messages by future engineers who arent aware of the security protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails provides [`rescue_from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) to catch errors in your application and respond to them with an appropriate error message.

When you want to catch all types of internal server errors, rescuing from `StandardError` might be the best option. Within the method handling the exceptions, you can render an HTML response, a JSON response or redirect the user with an error message depending on your needs and similar to normal controller methods.

```
# in app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  rescue_from StandardError, :handle_exceptions

private

def handle_exceptions
  render # ...
end
```

When you really want to catch *all* types of exceptions then you might want to rescue from `Exception` instead of `StandardError`. But be aware that this will also catch subclasses like `SyntaxError`, `LoadError`, and `Interrupt`.

In all cases I suggest manually login what exception was handled this way in the controller, to allow making debugging easier.

Comment: Thanks! So would rescuing from StandardError only catch internal server (5xx) errors? I want to make sure it isn’t catching 4xx errors too. I also have a base_controller.rb file that catches some of our errors, while the application_controller catches others. Does it matter which I put the rescue in?

Comment: There is nothing like a 5xx error or a 4xx error. What happens internally is that there are exceptions raised. And it is Ruby on Rails default to rescue from some exceptions automatically and render, for example, a 404 page instead of an `ActiveRecord:NotFoundException` server error. When you want to catch only some exceptions but not all of them then you have to decide what exceptions to handle and what to re-raise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have clarified what I meant by 4xx error. So basically it sounds like there’s no way to handle all the errors at once if I want to have specific behavior for errors where I’m raising a 5xx status?